# Appveyor: Package content hash validation failed, The package is different than the last restore

Tags: appveyor

I would like to configure CI in Appveyor for a .net project and I am struggling with following errors:

`error NU1403: Package content hash validation failed for System.Collections.NonGeneric.4.3.0. The package is different than the last restore.`

Every project restore happens to throw similar thing

[There was similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61883634/azure-devops-pipeline-dotnet-restore-package-content-hash-validation-fails) and one advice was to clear nuget cache.

Whats the best course of  action here?

Thanks

**Directory.Build.props**

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RestorePackagesWithLockFile>true</RestorePackagesWithLockFile>
    <DisableImplicitNuGetFallbackFolder>true</DisableImplicitNuGetFallbackFolder>
</PropertyGroup>
```

```
Build started
git config --global core.autocrlf true
git clone -q --branch=master https://github.com/User/App.git C:\projects\App
git checkout -qf 7066b969dd7564c573fb5e30fa6600a86c48644f
choco install opencover.portable
Chocolatey v0.11.3
Installing the following packages:
opencover.portable
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading opencover.portable 4.7.1221... 100%
opencover.portable v4.7.1221 [Approved]
opencover.portable package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
Downloading opencover.portable 
  from 'https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/releases/download/4.7.1221/opencover.4.7.1221.zip'
Progress: 100% - Completed download of C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\chocolatey\opencover.portable\4.7.1221\opencover.4.7.1221.zip (7.76 MB).
Download of opencover.4.7.1221.zip (7.76 MB) completed.
Hashes match.
Extracting C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\chocolatey\opencover.portable\4.7.1221\opencover.4.7.1221.zip to C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\opencover.portable\tools...
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\opencover.portable\tools
 ShimGen has successfully created a shim for OpenCover.Console.exe
 ShimGen has successfully created a shim for OpenCover.Simple.Target.exe
 ShimGen has successfully created a shim for OpenCover.Simple.Target.exe
 The install of opencover.portable was successful.
  Software installed to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\opencover.portable\tools'
Chocolatey installed 1/1 packages. 
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
Did you know the proceeds of Pro (and some proceeds from other
 licensed editions) go into bettering the community infrastructure?
 Your support ensures an active community, keeps Chocolatey tip-top,
 plus it nets you some awesome features!
 https://chocolatey.org/compare
choco install codecov
Chocolatey v0.11.3
Installing the following packages:
codecov
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading codecov 1.13.0... 100%
codecov v1.13.0 [Approved]
codecov package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
Extracting 64-bit C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\codecov\tools/codecov-win7-x64.zip to C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\codecov\tools...
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\codecov\tools
 ShimGen has successfully created a shim for codecov.exe
 The install of codecov was successful.
  Software installed to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\codecov\tools'
Chocolatey installed 1/1 packages. 
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
dotnet --version
5.0.403
dotnet restore
  Determining projects to restore...
C:\projects\App\Tests\Common.Tests\Common.Tests.csproj : error NU1403: Package content hash validation failed for System.Collections.NonGeneric.4.3.0. The package is different than the last restore. [C:\projects\App\App.sln]
```

**appveyor.xml**

```
version: '1.0.{build}'
image: Visual Studio 2019
branches:
  only:
  - master
init:
  - cmd: git config --global core.autocrlf true
install:
before_build:
  - choco install opencover.portable
  - choco install codecov
  - cmd: dotnet --version
  - cmd: dotnet restore
build_script:
  - cmd: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
test_script:
  - cmd: dotnet test  --configuration Release --no-build --no-restore --verbosity minimal --test-adapter-path:. --logger:Appveyor /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=TestResults/ /p:MergeWith="../TestResults/coverage.json"  /p:CoverletOutputFormat=lcov
cache:
  - '%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages -> **\project.json'
  - C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin -> appveyor.yml
  - C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib -> appveyor.yml
deploy: off
```

Comment: Is it a public project? Could you do a repo if not? Try removing `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages` from cache and deleting it instead before `dotnet restore`.

Comment: I removed `%USERPROFILE%` but it didn't [help much](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Jozefpodlecki/testci)

Comment: The issue could be in `packages.lock.json` files which contain that hash. I'm not sure why NuGet on AppVeyor build workers gets different hashes. Try deleting lock files before restore to see if that helps: `Get-ChildItem .\ -include packages.lock.json -Recurse | foreach ($_) { remove-item $_.fullname -Force }`

Comment: I tried that and it helped, but it looks like nuget caching does not work well in appveyor.

Comment: Could have been this https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7921#issuecomment-478152479 issue with differences in hash calculations in local nuget cache. Shudder.

Answer (score 1):

short and simple:

```
dotnet restore --force-evaluate
```

Forces restore to reevaluate all dependencies even if a lock file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

At [Feodor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435891/feodor-fitsner) suggestion I added powershell script which removes `package.lock.json` files and it worked.

```yaml
before_build:
  - choco install opencover.portable
  - choco install codecov
    - ps: >-
        Get-ChildItem .\ -include packages.lock.json -Recurse | foreach ($_) { remove-item $_.fullname -Force }
  - cmd: dotnet --version
  - cmd: dotnet restore
```